# Dynamic TypeScript signature for optional argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Alright so don't ask why but I am trying to implement a reduce method on subclass of Map:

```
const nah = Symbol('not-an-arg');

class MapArray<A, B> extends Map<A, B> {

    reduce<T = [A, B]>(f: (prev: T, next: [A, B]) => any, initialVal?: T) {

        let prev = arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[1] : nah;

        for (const [k, v] of this) {

            if (prev === nah) {
                prev = [k, v];
                continue;
            }

            prev = f(prev, [k, v]);

        }

        return prev;

    }

}
```

it's not the prettiest thing, but it basically works. The problem is the typing. If I do:

```
new MapArray<string,boolean>().reduce((a,b) => 'whatever');
```

versus:

```
new MapArray<string,boolean>().reduce((a,b) => 'whatever', []);
```

I want it to able to capture the type of the 2nd argument `[]`

using my *invalid* version of TS, I tried something like this:

```
 type X = (if initialVal ? typeof initialVal : [A, B])
 reduce<R = any, T = X>(f: (prev: T, next: [A, B]) => R, initialVal?: T);
```

this is obviously completely wrong, but hopefully you get the idea, doubt it's possible though. Does anyone know if I can capture the type of `initialVal` if it's passed, and if not, default to `[A,B]`?

here is the problem:
[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCGALGBeGBlAngWwEYgBsAKAcjBCgFp4xqAnAcxIEoBuAKHeAPgghgCy8AA4BBOnXiYAPKIA0MAEIA%20GAFMAHlDVgAJvyHDZClTADendjGsw6a3QFdga6QCVUMGpmVEAZgC4YImE7ADdAgG15JQBdBTBNKEjoxTiYAEs9TQB%20QLAHPDU6BQg1Al9cmChEdIhmVFVXZkDXDhtbeycXdzQvBQAVDy8fAKCQtXCYfvjE5JM0zN0cvILcIpKyisDq2vqURoVM9Kh0%20AIANTPA-uaYVqsbO0dnNyGwTAG37z9A4LDrmZaOaxQ5ZDSVfKFYowUrlSo7OoNO6g46nC5nSo3GAtcycdrtAhqWDjUJDRgFHRQCAAOkJYAY1RgqgAjDBsp5ydhKRAIsyYti4Eg2vjrITYItNB4AAwcB4i3wgOhBUCQWARADWClC-JAviqNURFjlIps6T1fwmqBQaAQiHqFhNjpgJI8Gq1MWFTvxKpO%20TUnqdAF88V7nWEPL4LaEFG6YNrQUsNABqJMKBFsEMi4PG9p2KAOOhgMMTWXtbPZ9gAekr%20rUMAVBAIIAA7pkGDBQNhhOlCRAFLgHOLYBBECAHARdGASP1LCqIIQ1LSQAwiMaEs3BCJxJIZJC1tDoHQ2z5mNTSlAiFKFCQFSAWGeiUQAEzX3DwOj3p5daTDIhEeD9nsqgOiac5qgAXgodD8r0AbtGBMCxtqHi4HBNhzguS4rmYAEwLggYZo6eYFkWJAkAGgYKAArFRzDsBmnBAA)

It will compile but "a is not iterable" (a as in first argument to the reduce callback)...a is not iterable because a is 55.

Comment: we might be able to use `infer` like so: https://learntypescript.dev/09/l2-conditional-infer

Comment: I am failing to see what the problem is here. I just checked your code in the Playground: https://tsplay.dev/Wkk7pW. In the first `reduce` call `initalVal` is not set, so `T` defaults to `[A,B]`. In the second call `initalVal` is set to `[]`, so the type of `T` is `never[]` (which is the type of the array). Isnt that exactly what you specified in the question?

Comment: there are a lot of things wrong with it, happy to do a screenshare or something tomorrow if you are up for it, hard to explain

Comment: I would just like to see a Playground where you show exactly the behaviour you are expecting here. And how the current behaviour differs from that.

Comment: I added a link a the bottom of OP. This compiles but it shouldn't. It should infer the type of `55` and then not compile - the code is trying to destructure 55 into an array of [k,v]. Actually, the code works as is, but I am looking for a way to write the code differently so that the above doesn't compile.

Comment: This now looks like you are looking for *Partial Type Inference* which TypeScript does not have. As soon as you explictly provide `any`  (or any other type) as a type parameter, TypeScript will *not* try to infer any other type parameters.

Comment: Well, that's fine, it might work as is, it's more that the declaration (syntax) doesn't make sense to me...like   `myFunc<T>(v: T)` should mean that the user provides T. Whereas if T is to be inferred from the argument, then different syntax should be used...my thinking was something like  `myFunc(v: <T>)` or what not...Or perhaps since it's not a list in this case `myFunc(v: ^T)` or something.

Comment: Is this just an exercise? There're many ready solutions out there that can do all this. [Here's one of them](https://gist.github.com/vitaly-t/129f82dc80a529f6ef7c8f334d1cdfc6).

Comment: Does iter-ops support TS? linking to the lib might be good

Answer (score 1):

A solution may be to use `undefined` instead of your `nah` and method overloading:

```ts
class MapArray<A, B> extends Map<A, B> {

    reduce(f: (prev: [A, B], next: [A, B]) => any): [A, B];
    reduce<T>(f: (prev: T, next: [A, B]) => any, initialVal: T): T;

    reduce<T>(f: (prev: T | [A, B], next: [A, B]) => any, initialVal?: T) {

        let prev: ([A, B] | T | undefined) = initialVal;
        let index = 0;

        for (const [k, v] of this) {

            if (prev === undefined) {
                prev = [k, v];
                continue;
            }

            prev = f(prev, [k, v]);

        }

        return prev;

    }

}

new MapArray<string,boolean>().reduce((a,b) => 'whatever');
new MapArray<string,boolean>().reduce((a,b) => 'whatever', []);
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/W4nv4N)

I see that this is quite similar to @Alexander Mills solution.

This is intended to be as close as possible with your original code, but I would like to point out that the return type of the function `f` should be the same as `prev` and in this case the returned value of your example function (the `string` `"whatever"`)doesn't work out.

Comment: you have to use `arguments.length` because the user could provide `undefined` as the initialVal; sad but true; luckily not that sad

Comment: @AlexanderMills  - I think [this](https://tsplay.dev/NarX0m) would discern between explicit `undefined` and missing second argument, right?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't 100% answer the original question, but it might help someone.

A partial solution is to use overloads like so:

```
reduce<R = any>(f: (prev: [A, B], next: [A, B]) => R): R;
reduce<R = any, T = any>(f: (prev: T, next: [A, B]) => R, initialVal?: T) {...}
```

the reason this doesn't really serve as an answer to OP is that I would like to grab the user-supplied type of initial val, instead of having to declare it with the generics parameter.

So again, looking to do something like:

```
reduce<R = any>(f: (prev: [A, B], next: [A, B]) => R): R;
reduce<R = any, T = typeof initialVal>(f: (prev: T, next: [A, B]) => R, initialVal?: <T>) {...}
```

Comment: I don't get your argument about your solution not capturing the type of `initialValue` - isn't that exactly why the generic type `T` was defined? Please look at the solution I just posted and help me understand what's missing.